# Switch Statements with strongly typed enumerations

Tags: c++, enums, c++11

When using strongly typed enums in a switch statement is there a way to avoid explicit casts to `int`?

```
/// @desc an enumeration of the states that the session can be in.
enum class State
{
    Created,    
    Connected,  
    Active,
    Closed
};

State sesState = session->GetState();

switch (static_cast<int>(sesState))
{
    case static_cast<int>(Session::State::Created):
    // do stuff.
    break;

    case static_cast<int>(Session::State::Connected):
    // do stuff.
    break;
}
```

From the n3242 draft:

6.4.2 The switch statement [stmt.switch]

2 The condition shall be of integral type, **enumeration type**, or of a class type for which a single non-explicit conversion function to integral or enumeration type exists (12.3).

Does **enumeration type** include strongly typed enums or are they incompatible with `switch` statements because they require an explicit conversion to `int`?

Comment: http://ideone.com/ZEJcs - compiles without conversions.

Comment: Came here with the same question, but it turns out Visual C++ 2015's intellisense is flagging false errors on the case statements with "this constant expression has type [...] instead of the required 'int' type." It compiles fine despite the red squiggly underlining.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

An enumeration type is still an enumeration type even whether strongly typed or not, and have always worked fine in `switch` statements.

See this program for example:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class E
{
    A,
    B
};

int main()
{
    E e = E::A;

    switch (e)
    {
    case E::A:
        std::cout << "A\n";
        break;
    case E::B:
        std::cout << "B\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

The output of this is "A".

Comment: isn't there a way to just say `case A` etc. perhaps with a `using` declarative?

Comment: @jiggunjer Yes it's possible, with e.g. `using E::A;`. However, that pulls in the symbol `A` in the current scope (and nested scopes of course), so you can't have another symbol named `A` anywhere else.

Comment: So you'd need a using for every enum member :(

Comment: @jiggunjer That's how strongly-typed enumerations work. If you don't want that then use normal enumerations.

Comment: I suppose I could put a normal enum in a namespace, but then I lose safety of no implicit casting... I just want better syntax for a switch!

Comment: When you say `switch (e)` it should already know to use the enum members without the bloaty syntax. Sorry for the rant :p

Comment: P.s. I just found out you can't do `using E::A` since E is not a namespace.

Comment: @jiggunjer It was introduced in C++11, and pulls basically makes `A` an alias for `E::A` in the current scope.

Comment: I am using -std=c++1y with g++ 4.9.  It gives me an error saying E is not a namespace.

Comment: @jiggunjer That's a bug in GCC then, both clang and later versions of GCC allows it.

Comment: How to get `e` from `std::cin` for our switch? `std::cin>>e` doesn't work.

Comment: @Franky One way is to read an integer, verify that it's a valid enumeration value, and then do an explicit cast to the enumeration (for strong enumerations like `enum class`). Another is to read a string, and do an explicit mapping (using e.g. `std::unordered_map`) to the enumeration value.

Comment: Tow long! So for a string based switch I don't have to use enum classes and can simply use strings.

Comment: @Franky But then you can't use `switch`. And there are use-cases when enumerations (strong or weak) are better than using string and string comparisons everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, just recalled that `switch` works merely on integer values. So I go for the  `std::unordered_map` since my desire is to use `enum class`.

Comment: @jiggunjer What you want exists, since C++20, as the [`using enum` declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Using-enum-declaration).